# How to iterate over xpath and check if image exists and perform operation based on that

Tags: python, selenium, if-statement, xpath, nosuchelementexception

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nnUvz.png)

As you can see in the image, I have 2 solutions (solution 1 is for a flight and solution 2 is for a hotel)

I want to iterate over each solution using XPATH. I am successful in that. I want to check the image returned on iteration.

My code is somewhat like this:

```
if select_solution.size != 0:
    print(str(i) + " solution selected")
    if '/assets/review/images/nodes/icon-plane.png' in driver.find_element(By.XPATH, config.RT_flightImage_check_Xpath.format(i)).get_attribute("src"):
        result['Solution ' + str(i)] = {}
                            print("Solution is for Flight")
                            print("**********************")
                            returned_solution = 'Flight'
                            result['Solution ' + str(i)]['Returned Solution'] = returned_solution
                        
elif 'assets/review/images/nodes/icon-hotel.png' in driver.find_element(By.XPATH, config.RT_HotelImage_check_Xpath.format(i)).get_attribute("src"):
                        result['Solution ' + str(i)] = {}
                        print("Solution is for Hotel")
                        print("**********************")
                        returned_solution = 'Hotel'
                        result['Solution ' + str(i)]['Returned Solution'] = returned_solution
```

Result:

```
Total number of Solutions found:  2
1 solution selected
Solution is for Flight
**********************
--------
2 solution selected
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//hgb-content-view[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/hgb-flight-content-view[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/img[1]"}
```

(Session info: chrome=103.0.5060.134)

The issue that i am facing is that when it iterates the 1st time, it finds the flight and does the necessary operation, but during the second iteration it fails because it does not find the flight (`No such element` exception).

How do I make sure that it goes to the `elif` and not exit cause the flight xpath is not found in the selected iteration?

Comment: 1) _goes to the elif_: Can you show us your goes to the elif 2) _No such element exception_: Update the question with the text based relevant HTML and the error stacktrace.

Comment: could it be the action causes the element to dissapear?

Comment: @undetectedSelenium updated my question with code snippet

Comment: **1)** Does `By.XPATH, config.RT_flightImage_check_Xpath.format(i)` resolves to `//hgb-content-view[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/hgb-flight-content-view[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/img[1]` **2)** Can you crosscheck if `elif` section is properly indented?

Comment: @undetectedSelenium it does hence the output has the solution for that. Elif is also indented perfectly. I am not sure what else to do as the code fails on second iteration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This actually worked. Had to tweak it a little instead of find_element, I used find_elements

```
try: 
    flight_element=driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, config.RT_flightImage_check_Xpath.format(i)) 
except Exception as e: 
    print(str(e)) elem=[] pass 
    
if len(flight_element) != 0 and '/assets/agent/icons/transaction/plane.svg' in driver.find_element(By.XPATH, config.AA_flight_icon_Xpath.format(i)).get_attribute("svg"):
```

and this way, in second iteration i was able to find the hotel and get the desired result

Answer (score 0):

```
try:
   elem=driver.find_element(By.XPATH, config.RT_flightImage_check_Xpath.format(i))
except Exception as e:
   print(str(e))
   elem=[]
   pass
```

Try except and catch the error and display it. Then do it for the other one.

```
if len(elem)!=0 and '/assets/review/images/nodes/icon-plane.png' in elem.get_attribute("src"):
    #your code
elif len(elem2)!=0 and 'assets/review/images/nodes/icon-hotel.png' in elem2.get_attribute("src"):
    #your code
```

Comment: This actually worked. Had to tweak it a little

instead of find_element, I used find_elements
` 
try:
   flight_element=driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, config.RT_flightImage_check_Xpath.format(i))
except Exception as e:
   print(str(e))
   elem=[]
   pass
`

`
if len(flight_element) != 0 and '/assets/agent/icons/transaction/plane.svg' in driver.find_element(By.XPATH, config.AA_flight_icon_Xpath.format(i)).get_attribute("svg"):
`

and this way, in second iteration i was able to find the hotel and get the desired result